# According to my last post on 'diamond district' capitalization and answer posted, 'diamond district' can be capitalized or not?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, capitalization

Sentence One: **The Diamond District** is a commercial stretch between Fifth and Sixth avenues in Midtown Manhattan, encompasses only nearly one block.
note in Wikedpedia I found this sentence with 'diamond district' capitalized.

Sentence 2: I went to **the diamond district** in New York.
**note:** Both sentences appear to be accepted. Are you saying that I have the choice of capitalizing or not capitalizing diamond district as long as I remain consistence? Of course, there are some districts that are **not** capitalized as you mentioned in **Answer reply** on previous post like 'the financial district' and 'the industrial district," etc. Other than the districts you mentioned in previous **Answer post**, how would I know as a beginner proofreader what other districts are capitalized or not? Is there a list?

Comment: As @David Siegel said in his answer to your earlier question, _a frequently used description can become an informal name_. There is no hard and fast rule.  If enough people refer to the area in that way, it gradually comes to be thought of as a 'proper noun'.

Comment: Of course they're both accepted. No, no-one is saying you have an option here. A generic description is never capitalized like "the industrial district" or "the diamond district". Only when that becomes a formal name is it capitalized. You have to know the area to know whether it is a place name or a generic description.